# In what way and in which cases we have to use the NSFastEnumeration in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In what way and in which cases we have to use the NSFastEnumeration in iphone can anyone tell me the sample codes to how to use these fast enumeration in iphone

Comment: A quick search of the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18) will tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

`NSFastEnumeration` is a protocol that your classes can adopt that allows you to use the fast enumeration construct for iterating over a collection of objects managed by your class. That is you will be able to write:

```
for (Object * obj in MYAwesomeObject) {
    //do awesome stuff here.
}
```

The built-in collection classes in Foundation already implement this (NSArray, NSSet, NSDictionary) which cover many many needs for collection objects. If, say, you wanted to implement a particular tree structure, you can have your class adopt `NSFastEnumeration` to allow you to iterate over all the objects in the tree without having to handle traversing directly. In this case, your class has to implement `-countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` to conform to the protocol which returns (through reference) a C array of objects to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

[`NSFastEnumeration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18) is here to speed op loops.

So dont use:

```
for (in i =0; i < [myArray count]; i++){
  id object [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

but use:

```
for (id object in myArray)
```

<strike>This will make the looping thru the array much faster</strike>.

Comment: There is no performance benefit (despite the 'fast' in the name) for arrays. If you looked at the disassembly then I'm sure that you would see the same operations happening. It is more of a syntactic convenience.